# Dynamically update JList from events

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist, eventhandler

I have a `JList` that takes elements from an `ArrayList` of objects and displays some elements from the object in the list pane. When I select that element it displays the full information in other fields and labels. As part of my programme implementation I am also able to add and remove objects to the `ArrayList`. What I would like to do is each time the `ArrayList` is changed the `JList` will update to reflect the new state of the `ArrayList`. Below is the code for my `JList` element.

```
    DefaultListModel<String> defListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    if(studentList.size() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++){
            Student aStudent = studentList.get(i);
        defListModel.addElement(aStudent.toString());
        }
    }
    JList<String> list = new JList<String>(defListModel);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = list.getSelectionModel();
    listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new SelectionListener());
    scroll.setBounds(16, 24, 130, 205);
    mainPanel.add(scroll);
```

How would I go about dynamically updating this list as items are added and removed? Please do not provide a full solution (as I find I learn better by doing) but any helpful hints or suggestions where I could find a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) has all the methods you need:

```
void    DefaultListModel#addElement(E element);
void    DefaultListModel#add(int index, E element);
E       DefaultListModel#remove(int index);
boolean DefaultListModel#removeElement(Object obj)
```

As you add/remove items from your list, you can make the same modification to the JList's model.

---

If you just make updates to your `DefaultListModel`, you can recover your `ArrayList` with:

```
studentList = Collections.list(defListModel.elements());  // creates new ArrayList
```

or, if other references to studentList must be maintained:

```
studentList.clear();
studentList.addAll(Collections.list(defListModel.elements()));
```

**EDIT** Whoops!  Sorry.  Your `ArrayList<?> studentList` is of a <s>unknown</s> unspecified type ; we can't recover the original list.  Even the `ArrayList<String>` of student names cannot be reliably matched back to individual students, since `#toString()` may return a different `String` each time it is called, depending on how it is implemented, and student names may not be unique.  You'll just have to do the same operations to both lists.

---

**EDIT** The default renderer for a `JList` will call `#toString()` on the objects in the list.  Instead of calling `defListModel.addElement(aStudent.toString())`, you could add the actual objects to the appropriately typed `JList`/`DefaultListModel`.

```
DefaultListModel<Student> defListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
// ...
    defListModel.addElement(aStudent);
// ...
JList<Student> list = new JList<>(defListModel);
```

With this change, the defListModel can be modified, and the corresponding changes to the student list can be recovered with:

```
studentList = Collections.list(defListModel.elements());
```

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions immediately come to mind:

1. Don't use an ArrayList at all,

   - instead use the DefaultListModel to hold your collection of data.
   - Then any time you add or remove items from this model, the JList is automatically updated.
2. Or yes, use an ArrayList to hold your data

   - And then use this same ArrayList as the nucleus of your own code-created JList data model.
   - This means **not** using a DefaultListModel but rather extend from `AbstractListModel<MyType>`.
   - Then whenever you add or remove data from your ArrayList, you **must** remember to call the appropriate AbstractListModel `fireXxx(...)` method so that the model will notify the view (here the JList) of changes, so it can change its display.